# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, chart.js

Estoy tratando de hacer graficas en Chartjs en conjunto con Gatsbyjs, pero cuando ejecuto mi ruta en donde se encuentra la grafica que quiero mostrar me aparece el error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null' debido a esto no me puede mostrar la gráfica.
Aquí dejo mi código

```js
const jsonfile = {
  "jsonarray": [
  {
     "Anio":2016,
     "Bovino":"48,148.76",
     "Porcino":"10,153.27"
  },
  {
     "Anio":2017,
     "Bovino":"45,501.43",
     "Porcino":"10,801.30"
  },
  {
     "Anio":2018,
     "Bovino":"46,365.48",
     "Porcino":"11,010.21"
  },
  {
     "Anio":2019,
     "Bovino":"44,627.29",
     "Porcino":"10,228.82"
  }
]
};
const labels = jsonfile.jsonarray.map(function(e) {
  return e.Anio;
});
const dataBovino = jsonfile.jsonarray.map(function(e) {
  return +e.Bovino.replace(',',''); 
});
const dataPorcino = jsonfile.jsonarray.map(function(e) {
  return +e.Porcino.replace(',','');
});
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
     labels: labels,
     datasets: [{
        label: 'Bovino',
        data: dataBovino,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.3)'
     },
     {
        label: 'Porcino',
        data: dataPorcino,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(230, 119, 204, 0.3)'
     }]
  } 
};

const chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
  

export default function Grafica() {
    return <div align='center'>
        <h2>Producción de leche</h2>
        <Bar
          data={{dataBovino,dataPorcino}}
          width={100}
          height={40}
          options={chart}
        />
      </div>
}
```

Así es la forma en como se puede mostrar una grafica de chart e gatsby, espero puedan ayudarme, desconozco mi error

Supongo que en esto se encuentra en error **const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');** en realidad no se que suceda, porque en html este codigo si funciona bien, pero yo necesito que este chart vaya con gatsby

Comment: Asegúrate que tienes un elemento `<canvas>` en tu html generado, porque `document.querySelector('canvas')` no te está retornando nada.

Comment: Si, lo tengo en la parte superior, pero pareciera que no lo reconoce @AlterLagos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debe de estar pasando es que en el momento en que ejecutas esta línea `const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');` el elemento `canvas` aún no se ha procesado (no existe en el DOM), por este motivo al hacer cualquier función sobre él en este punto falla (`const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');` es nulo aunque lo pongas arriba).

La solución es hacerlo cuando el componente ya se ha procesado y los elementos ya están disponibles en el DOM.

Te recomiendo que revises el Hook de efecto `useEffect` para controlar esto.

Documentación aquí: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

Todo lo que necesitas hacer es el documento JavaScript lo pongas al final ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <!--Tu codigo de la cabeza-->
</head>
<body>
   <!--Tu codigo de el body-->
<script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

El problema no es tu script, es tu posición del src.